# How to maintain the same radius of magnifier circle while zooming canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to implement a functionality in *fabric.js* where I have to zoom an image using magnifier and mouse scroll. I have almost achieved it, the only problem is that while zooming the canvas (by mouse scroll), the magnifier circle is also zooming.

```js
(function () {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    var radius = 100,
        x = 300,
        y = 300,
        lens,
        scale = 2,
        originalWidth = 600,
        originalHeight = 600;

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {
        img.set({
            width: originalWidth,
            height: originalHeight,
            evented: true,
            selectable: false
        });

        lens = fabric.util.object.clone(img);
        lens.set({
            width: scale * originalWidth,
            height: scale * originalHeight,
            clipTo: function (ctx) {
                ctx.arc(-this.left + x - this.width / 2, -this.top + y - this.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            }
        });

        canvas.add(img, lens);
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
        x = e.e.layerX;
        y = e.e.layerY;
        lens.set('left', -(scale - 1) * x);
        lens.set('top', -(scale - 1) * y);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });


var canvasarea = document.getElementById("canvases");
canvasarea.addEventListener("mousewheel", _zoomCanvas, false);
/// Firefox
canvasarea.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", _zoomCanvas, false);


function _zoomCanvas(e, dragDelta, isDragged) {  
  var evt=window.event || e;
  var delta = (dragDelta == undefined) ? evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta : dragDelta;

  var curZoom = canvas.getZoom(),  newZoom = curZoom + delta / 4000,
  x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;

  if(newZoom < 0 || newZoom < canvas.scaleX) return;     
  ///applying zoom values.
  canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: x, y: y }, newZoom);
 
 if(e != null)e.preventDefault();
 return false;
} 




})();
```

```css
canvas{
  border-width: 1pz;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/build/files/text,gestures,easing,parser,freedrawing,interaction,serialization,image_filters,gradient,pattern,shadow,node.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvases">
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ankur02/kvht1637/

Comment: To invert the zoom value is. `var invZoom = 1 / canvas.getZoom();` so if you want the radius to remain constant. `radius = 100 * invZoom;`

Comment: Thanks for reply @Blindman67 , it working  :)

Comment: Please can you answer this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521876/how-to-change-image-url-of-cloned-image-in-fabric-js-without-changing-it-other-p

Comment: Hi, I have a similar code but I am doing: canvas.centerObject(img)
So, it's no working because I center the image in the canvas, please help...